# Make a model a collection of itself

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, model, sails.js

The title may not be clear, but what I want to achieve is to have Categories with parentCategories. For example:

```
/-Clothes
/---Men
/---Women
/---Kids
/-----Newborns
```

So I thought I could make every category have an optional parent category and whenever I add a category with a parent one, find this parent category and add the new subCategory to it as well. Am I clear?

This is what I've done so far:

Category.js (Model)

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'MongoDB',

  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    description: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    products: {
      collection: 'product',
      via: 'category'
    },
    parentCategory: {
      model: 'category'
    },
    subCategories: {
      collection: 'category',
      via: 'parentCategory'
    },

    addSubCategory: function(sc) {
      this.subCategories.push(sc);
    }
  }
};
```

It doesnt seem to be working. I'm calling addSubCategory from my controller, sc and this values are correct, but it never adds the "subCategory" attribute to the category. I know this may not be the best approach, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `subCategories` attribute. Following design would be my suggestion.

```
  module.exports = {
    connection: 'MongoDB',

    attributes: {
      name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        unique: true
      },
      type: {
        type: 'string',
        enum: ['parent', 'subcategory'],
      },
      description: {
        type: 'string'
      },
      products: {
        collection: 'product',
        via: 'category'
      },
      parentCategory: {
        model: 'category' // this exists only if type is 'subcategory' else null
      },

      addSubCategory: function(sc) {
        this.subCategories.push(sc);
      }
    }
  };
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: This wouldnt search for the parent category and add the new suncategory to it. I want that to populate the categories  hierarchically

Comment: You can also create another model for `Subcategory` but design wise I think this model should work perfectly. You can populate data using `async` blocks.